# How can I convert my code into a single line?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have the following code which I would like to convert into a single line I guess using list comprehension? But I have been unsuccessful in converting it.

```
exp_days = ["16/04/2021","23/04/2021","27/04/2021"]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df["Date"][i] in exp_days:
        list_of_days.append(1)
    else:
        list_of_days.append(0)
```

My dataframe:

```
Date
16/04/2021
19/04/2021
20/04/2021
21/04/2021
22/04/2021
23/04/2021
26/04/2021
27/04/2021
```

Expected output:

```
list_of_days = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
```

Comment: "But I have been unsuccessful in converting it." So what have you tried? In how far have you been unsuccessful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_of_days = [ 1 if df["Date"][i] in exp_days else 0 for i in range(len(df)) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative via numpy -

```
exp_days = ["16/04/2021","23/04/2021","27/04/2021"]
import numpy as np
result = np.where(df['Date'].isin(exp_days),1,0)
```